# D3 drawing circles on the circumference of other circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was trying to build a chart which is similar to here

https://sf.relsci.com/Visualizations/davos

How can i draw the circles in a circular shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ksWDN/) with one way to do it.

```
.attr('transform', function (d, i) {
    return "translate(" + ((w/2-r) * Math.cos((interval*i) * Math.PI/180)) + "," + ((w/2-r) * Math.sin((interval*i) * Math.PI/180)) + ")";
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you FernOfTheAndes, that really helps me, and one more query can we move circles closer means the space between circles should be Zero.

Comment: You just need to play with the parameters...if you set `w = r * 2.43` you should get no spacing between circles.