# Circle pattern in d3

Tags: d3.js

[image]

I am trying to draw an image like this using d3. Can someone please guide me on how I can determine the x and y coordinates of each of the small circles?

Comment: You would divide the total 360 degree circle by the number of small circles. This, together with the index of the individual circles and the sum of radii of the big and small circles, gives you the position of each circle.

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954207/d3-drawing-circles-on-the-circumference-of-other-circle#22956798) should help. It was actually based on a similar answer provided by Lars.